# Show a div only on specific page while loading scripts from multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div called `uname` defined in a file called `header.html`. I do not want to show this div on one of the couple of pages I have which are `home.html` and `dash.html`.

`header.html` is being loaded on both of the pages. How can I hide this particular div `uname` on `home.html` and show it just on `dash.html`?

I am using jquery to load the `header.html` file:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#header").load("header.html")
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code and add the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#header").load("header.html",function(){
       $('.uname').hide();
    //of if uname is an id then
       $('#uname').hide();
    });
});
```

Basically what we are doing here is hiding the div when it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you could query for the current url, and depending on the result, you can include or not your div.

A sample code could look like:

```
<?php 
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($page == 'dash.html'){
  echo '<div class="uname"> div content here </div>'; // put your div inside this echo
} 
?>
```

Add the code above, with the changes you need, in your header.html and when you load a page that includes the header, it will also check for the page URL and load or not your div.

Comment: I am not using php